# importing JSON to mongoDB using pymongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

i am trying to import a JSON file i pull from a URL and send it to mongoDB as is, using the pymongo module.

I have the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, urllib2, json, pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
myurl = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/border/775526/raw/b921df18ba00262ab5bba8cadb3c178e1f7748f7/config.json"
response = urllib2.urlopen(myurl)
data = response.read()
connection = MongoClient('mongodb://user:password@localhost.com:27017/database')
connection.database_names()
db = connection.database
posts = db.posts
post_id = posts.insert_many(data).inserted_id
```

upon executing this, i get this error
raise TypeError("documents must be a non-empty list")
TypeError: documents must be a non-empty list

ideally, i want to just be able to pull the json from the url and update the mongoDB as this json file will be updated every week.
Thanks

Comment: Well, have you debugged your code to check at every stage what each variable holds, both data and type?

Comment: To import local file, is the urllib2 required? Or I can do this in other way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to convert JSON to Python objects, which PyMongo will then convert to BSON for sending to MongoDB. To convert JSON to Python objects use the "bson.json_util" module included with PyMongo:

```
from bson import json_util
data = json_util.loads(response.read())
```

The standard Python json.loads() function works, too, but PyMongo's json_util.loads() handles some MongoDB-specific details better.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the "requests" library:

```
response = requests.get(myurl)
data = response.json()
```

and post that data to the database.