# Pymongo how to import json file into mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a local json file and I need to import the json file into mongodb using Pymongo. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Answer (score -1):

You already have the answer, for more details read the documentation about pymongo.

[importing JSON to mongoDB using pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095786/importing-json-to-mongodb-using-pymongo) [Here stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095786/importing-json-to-mongodb-using-pymongo)

```
from bson import json_util
data = json_util.loads(response.read())
```

Comment: I've read this post, so where should I put the directory of the local file? It's not an url